# How to increment or add storage (up to 500Gb) to new AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I want to create new instance in the AWS cloud. The standard space is 8Gb which is not enough for my purpose.

I have my application in the `/var/www`-directory where files from users get uploaded. I need the additional space for these files. After the user uploaded the file i will move them to my S3 storage.

How can i increment the storage limit of a new instance or add new volume (EBS) mounted as `/dev/sdb` at `/var`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I tried to make the title of your question a little more legible. I also tried to summarize your question a little and make the structure a little more understandable to increase the likelihood of getting an answer. I hope I succeeded. Good luck!